# GRUB doesn't find theme in Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: grub2, 22.04, themes

Installed Ubuntu 22.04.2, haven't been aroud since 18.04, man o man! Ubuntu sure has changed a lot and has a lot of bugs even though it's an LTS version! I've been configuring it like for a week now and still it's not the Ubuntu I want it to be... Just btw.

I tried installing several GRUB themes with grub-customizer, got this problem.
Also tried it manually, same thing happens.
When I run `sudo update-grub` or `sudo update-grub2` I don't get the:

```
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/*theme*/theme.txt
```

output in the output of the command...
Tried some things that came to mind, googled, but no luck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use another theme

Comment: No, as I said, tried several themes, and no luck. IDK what the heck is the matter with this 22.04! In a way, it's a good Ubuntu version, but so many things have changed and this causes a lot of problems, so many bugs! I had to do a ton of configuration in order for my general Ubuntu customization to work... But yet, I'm staying on Ubuntu, it's the best.

Comment: can you make clean installation of ubuntu 22.04 lts

Comment: Don't even ask! As I said, I made a ton of GUI and security and etc. configurations on this one, so... no! not at all! Thank u but this is not a good solution, if it were up to re-installation, then wtf was the difference between GNU/Linux and Windows!? :D In this ~15years of experience on linux, I never reinstalled my linux distro because of a problem! That's my image of mind from linux, that u can solve any problem in it, u just have to be that good of a hacker or get help from one which is what I'm doing here, I gave up trying coz I was cheating on Ubuntu with another distro for a time..!:D

Comment: ...and Ubuntu has changed a lot as I said and I'm sorry I wasn't around to see these changes in action/live! I also have other things I've got to do or else maybe I could have fixed it myself if I put enough time. Sorry for the blabber!

Comment: Anyone.........?

Answer (score 0):

if your theme extracted to `/boot/grub/themes/urthemname` try to add the theme to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

scroll to this part:

```
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hdx,msdosx'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hdx,msdosx --hint-efi=hdx,msdosx --hint-baremetal=ahcix,msdosx  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
fi
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/terminus-12.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/terminus-14.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/terminus-16.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/terminus-18.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/ubuntu_regular_17.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/ubuntu_regular_20.pf2
insmod png
set theme=($root)/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/theme.txt
export theme
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=3
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
```

you will find `x`  no. or litter dont chang it

 replace `urthemname` with your theme name, `sudo update-grub`

 if you can not do this, try to edit `/etc/default/grub`  and add this `GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/urthemname/theme.txt"` in the last line `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks. my /boot/grub/grub.cfg doesn't have this part of codes in it! should I add these codes to it? if I should, where? at the end of the file? or which part of the codes should I add? all of them or a part of them?

Comment: @S0h3iL updated answer, look at 2 last lines

Comment: Please see my new answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress, at least I figured out why the `'Found theme: ...'` line doesn't appear.
I ended up installing a fresh install of Ubuntu! I edited the */etc/default/grub* file and installed the theme the usual way by hand (manually) (by adding GRUB_THEME and etc) and when I comment the line Grub console like this:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

it shows me the:

```
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/*/theme.txt
```

line.
But when I remove the # at the first of the line, it no longer shows the found theme line.
And the thing is when I do this and reboot it doesn't show the grub menu at all, neither with theme nor without theme!
So far we know the problem is probably because of this damn 'GRUB_TERMINAL=console ' line. So with that in mind, any idea why this happens?

Seriously, I wonder why nobody has had this problem before! When I first ran into it I Googled and expected that I'll find a good link that people had this issue and somebody explained how to fix it but Probably I'm the first person who reports this issue!
Please help, no linux problem has taken me this long to fix and I've been on GNU/Linux for about 15years now and that's why it's a pain in my ass that I can't figure out the fix...